# Node.js command line script sometimes does not terminate

Tags: node.js, babeljs, babel-node

I have a node js script with an async main method. Sometimes the script terminates fine, other times it hangs.

```
const main = async () => {
    let updates = []
    // ... add a bunch of promises to updates
    await Promise.all(updates)
} 

main()
```

Does anyone know why this script sometimes might hang? It just doesn't terminate though it appears to have run to completion.

Comment: It's impossible to be certain based on what  you provide here, but generally this happens if you fail to resolve or reject all your promises and/or don't call `process.exit()` appropriately.

Comment: Yes this happens to me a lot--your async function inherently returns a promise even though nothing is explicitly returned. So if you add `main().then(() => process.exit())` it should always terminate.

Answer (score 10):

Because your function is `async`, you need to explicitly terminate it when it finishes:

```
main().then(() => process.exit())
```